# imac: keyboard stuck on caps lock

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac

From time to time the (Apple USB) keyboard of my imac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010, mac os 10.12.5) gets stuck on caps lock (namely all letters are printed capital, and I can't turn capital off), and I have to unplug the USB cable to fix this; when I plug it back, the light is on, and I can turn caps lock off. This happens more frequently after installing mac os updates, then it gradually becomes less frequent.

Are there an explanation and a solution for this issue?

Comment: More than likely, you need a new keyboard.  Try it with a different keyboard (even a PC keyboard will work).  If the problem goes away, you have your answer.

Comment: This was happening to me too. So weird. Unplugging the keyboard worked

Answer (score -2):

Just unplug the USB from the back of your computer. Plug the USB back into the computer. Solved.

Comment: It looks like the author of the question was already doing that ...

Comment: You don't seem to have actually read the whole question.  Best delete this answer.